# Append multiple directories contents to one file with AWK?

Tags: linux, awk

I've got a shell script which merges all my migration and seeder files to two bigger files, but I want to merge migrate.sql and seed.sql into just one big file called deploy.sql.

Is there a way with AWK to accept multiple directories into one final file?

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p output
awk '{print}' ./migrations/*.sql > "output/migrate.sql"
awk '{print}' ./seeders/*.sql > "output/seed.sql"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way with AWK to accept multiple directories into one final
> file?

GNU `AWK` does not accept directories, but rather files, in your case

```
awk '{print}' ./migrations/*.sql > "output/migrate.sql"
awk '{print}' ./seeders/*.sql > "output/seed.sql"
```

argument with `*` is replaced by all files compliant with descripition *before* being rammed into `awk`, consider following example, say you have only following files in current dir

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

which are empty then

```
awk 'BEGIN{print ARGV[1],ARGV[2],ARGV[3]}' file*.txt
```

does output

```
file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Observe that even in BEGIN, [`ARGV`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/ARGC-and-ARGV.html) has entry for each file, rather than single entry with `file*.txt`.

You might use more than 1 argument with `*` when using GNU `AWK` that is you might do

```
awk '{print}' ./migrations/*.sql ./seeders/*.sql > "output/deploy.sql"
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*